# warning: passing argument 1 of 'setLife:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Just wondered if anyone could help, im getting the warning above with the following code:

**.h**

```
int *life;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *life;
```

**.m**

```
self.life = 100;
```

and

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setPercentage:' on

```
self.progressTimer.percentage = self.life;
```

Just wondered if anyone could help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a pointer for basic datatypes, unless absolutely required (most often you won't in Objective-C).

Declare your int like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int life;
```

And your issue should be solved.